# Table drawing in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I would like to draw a table with 2 columns. The first column will have 2 rows each one containing a and b letters respectively and the second column containing no rows. here is my code.

```
Public Class trialtable
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub trialtable(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim trial As DataTable
        trial = New DataTable
        Dim tbl As New Table()

        Dim szName As String = ""
        Dim szNumber As String = ""
        Dim szsadasd As String = ""
        tbl.BorderColor = Drawing.Color.Black
        tbl.BorderWidth = 1
        tbl.CellPadding = 0
        tbl.CellSpacing = 0

        For i As Integer = 0 To 1
            Dim tr As New TableRow()
            Dim tc1 As New TableCell()
            Dim tc2 As New TableCell()
            Dim tc3 As New TableCell()
            tc1.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl(szName))
            tc2.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl(szNumber))
            tc3.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl(szsadasd))
            tc1.BorderColor = Drawing.Color.Black
            tc1.BorderWidth = 1
            tc2.BorderColor = Drawing.Color.Black
            tc2.BorderWidth = 1
            tc3.BorderColor = Drawing.Color.Black
            tc3.BorderWidth = 1
            tr.Cells.Add(tc1)
            tr.Cells.Add(tc2)
            tr.Cells.Add(tc3)
            tbl.Controls.Add(tr)
        Next
        Me.Controls.Add(tbl)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Sounds like homework to me... if that is the case, please tag the question as such

Comment: its not a homework its a task in my office but the case is i never used tables i always use gridviews

Comment: What is stopping you creating the table directly in the HTML markup?

Comment: And if you want "2 columns" why are you creating and adding 3 `TableCell` objects to the row each time?

Comment: first i removed the 3rd cell and the team leader didnt want me to use html he wanted it in vb  code

Answer (score 0):

In order to place the value `a` in the first cell of the first row, and `b` in the first cell of the 2nd row, and have nothing in the 2nd cell of both rows, replace the following lines of code...

```
tc1.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl(szName))
tc2.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl(szNumber))
```

With the following code...

```
If i = 0 Then
    tc1.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("a"))
Else
    tc1.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("b"))
End If
tc2.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("&nbsp;"))
```